# dompdf - just getting two pages in pdf

Tags: html, pdf, twig, symfony, dompdf

i want to print a html to a pdf. In the project i use symfony and twig to render the template. When i return the html to browser it's looking good.
And it should be about 10 pages.

But when i try to create the PDF, i just get two pages.

```
$html = $this->render('offer/print.html.twig', array('offer' => $Offer )); 

$options = new Options();
$options->setIsRemoteEnabled( false );

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf( $options );
$dompdf->setPaper('A4');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->loadHtml( $html );
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

PHP 7
Symfony 3.0.9
dompdf 0.7.0

It doesn't looks like the html in the browser. I have to debug the css later.
Can anyone tell me why i just getting two pages in the pdf?

Comment: why output buffer at all? If the render call returns the rendered data to $html, then there's NO point in buffering, echoing $html, only so you can capture into $output. why not just have `$output = $this->render...` instead?

Comment: @MarcB i tried this, too.
and also 
$dompdf->loadHtml( $this->render( ));

Comment: Hard to tell without the proper HTML output and CSS, dompdf can be a pita to handle. Make sure you've set the right dimensions in your CSS as well

Answer (score 1):

interesting it seems the problem is the `render()` function.
When i use `renderView()` instead i got my output over multiple pages.

`render()` also returns the HTTP Headers. Out of this reason i got a broken pdf with the header information on the first side and all content on the second.

Just the CSS isn't working but this is another issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Please upload you twig file. I think the issues with you twig css.